# Databind Components to Table from DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I created a method that databinds components with table from a datasource.:

```
private void AddDataBinding()
    {
        txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Ticket.RaffleID");
        cboName.DataBindings.Add("Value", ds, "Ticket.CustomerID");
        dtpDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", ds, "Ticket.Date");
        txtStore.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Ticket.Store");
        txtAmount.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Ticket.Amount");
        txtStub.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Ticket.NoStub");

        cm = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[ds, "Ticket"];
    }

private void frmCustomerTicket_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        AddDataBinding();
    }
```

When I run the code this message appeared: "Child list for field Ticket cannot be created."

Comment: What is the possible reason of this error?

Comment: have you tried setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember?